# How to choose right graphics card for 3ds Max?

Tags: 3ds-max, hardware-recommendation

I want to configure a PC which should be used mainly for working with `AutoCAD` and `Autodesk 3ds Max 2013/2014`. I'm searching for the best value for the price graphics card.

On the internet all forums and benchmarks are mainly for `Geforce Quadro` series for such kind of work, but they are too expensive for me.

So I'm wondering if `Geforce GTX` series will also work fine with 3D design and rendering. Currently I'm looking into `Geforce GTX 750`, `GTX 780` and `GTX 970`.

Please let me know if you have an experience of working with one of these devices and if you would recommend them. Thanks.

Comment: http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/syscert?siteID=123112&id=18844534&results=1&stype=graphic&product_group=6&release=2015&os=32768&manuf=all&opt=1

Comment: @Joonas I'm familiar with the reference, but there are only 2 version of GTX graphics cards which are also expensive. However 'not recommended' or 'not certified' doesn't mean it will not work good.

Comment: Well it does not mean its not usable, but also means if you have support problems they will laugh at your face. Anything else is a gamble, and if you can afford to use MAX you can afford a workstation (in fact you can not afford not getting the best)

Comment: I just wonder why you can't choose a Quadro. I am using an entry level K600, and it works very well. Leave the game cards to kids playing video games. Wait...